# Activity gets closed after pressing the button

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Here I am trying to Open a Activity Named **LevelActivity** from **MainActivity** on Button click event, But When I try to open My LevelActivity It throw me out side of the Application. The **XML** and **JAVA** Files Are Given below.

**My LevelActivity.java**

```
public class LevelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level);

    Button btnEasy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEasy);
    Button btnHard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHard);
    Button btnNormal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNormal);

    btnEasy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int seconds = 120;
            int Live = 10;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LevelActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("varSeconds", seconds);
            myIntent.putExtra("varLive", Live);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });


    btnHard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int seconds = 60;
            int Lives = 5;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LevelActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("varSeconds", seconds);
            myIntent.putExtra("varLive", Lives);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });


    btnNormal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int seconds = 60;
            int Live = 10;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LevelActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("varSeconds", seconds);
            myIntent.putExtra("varLive", Live);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

}}
```

**Code for ActivityMain.java**

*This is my main Activity where I want to Navigate from Main to Level Activity as I said before*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton btnMathPlay, btnMathShare, btnMathRate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnMathPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMathPlay);
    btnMathShare= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMathShare);
    btnMathRate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMathRate);

    btnMathPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
             *  Example of Explicit Intent
             *  When you click Play Button on the screen
             *  Game Activity will be started
             */

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LevelActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btnMathShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
             *  Example of Implict Intent
             *  When you click Share Button on the screen
             *  Android will find the activities that allow to share messages.
             */

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Just Maths - Fun way to learn Maths. http://www.play.google.com");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnMathRate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
             *  Simple Toast Message To Display Message For Short Duration
             *  Link that to your app landing page.
             */
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You can open your Google Play landing page",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

**Here Is My XML File for LevelActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
tools:context=".LevelActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEasy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
    android:text="Easy" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNormal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnEasy"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnEasy"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnEasy"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@+id/btnEasy"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:text="Normal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnNormal"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnEasy"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnEasy"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
    android:text="Hard" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Please Help me to resolve this Problme and also if you want any other file like cat log something please mention!!**

**Here Is what I found on Debug Console**
Hope so This will help

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: cheezycode.com.justmaths, PID: 1634
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cheezycode.com.justmaths/cheezycode.com.justmaths.LevelActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2487)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5604)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    at cheezycode.com.justmaths.LevelActivity.onCreate(LevelActivity.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6358)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5604) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) 
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:668)
    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7086)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:1241)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:1087)
    at 
  android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:84)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:841)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
```

Comment: it would help if we could see your logcat

Comment: Have u declared your LevelActivity in Manifest?

Comment: Yes I have declared LevelActivity in My Manifest

Comment: please don't let people guess, add your logcat so we can provided more informed answers

Comment: @NikosHidalgo ok I will !

Comment: Add your logcat

Comment: @basic I just Added my logcat, Make sure you check It

Comment: @Arbazkdr the provided log is irrelevant. add the stack-trace of the error.

Comment: @MartinZeitler can you help me out? How can I stack-trace

Comment: The error you posted is not relevant.

Comment: look for exceptions in your logcat. when your app crashes you should see something like java.lang.nameOfException: ... followed by the line in the code where the exception happens

Comment: @Arbazkdr filter the log-cat for `LevelActivity`; some random log won't show the reason.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this is where it's wrong:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="@+id/btnEasy"
```

margin should be a number, not a view.

if your intention was to place it next to that view, use:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnEasy"
```

also everytime you refer to an existing view, you shouldn't include the + symbol. This only goes when you name a new view on its id attribute.

Comment: check my updated post, you need to change your code in various places

Answer (score -1):

Finally After making so much confusing I just rewrite all code again and Picking out some mistakes and make change in LevelActivity with this code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LevelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int seconds = 120;
          //  int Live = 10;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LevelActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("secondA", seconds);
            startActivity(myIntent);

           // myIntent.putExtra("varLive", Live);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int seconds = 60;
            //  int Live = 10;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LevelActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("secondA", seconds);
            startActivity(myIntent);

            // myIntent.putExtra("varLive", Live);
        }
    });

    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int seconds = 40;
            //  int Live = 10;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LevelActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("secondA", seconds);
            startActivity(myIntent);

            // myIntent.putExtra("varLive", Live);
        }
    });
}
}
```